# Import.io JSON Data import to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, json, import.io

I am trying to connect to and get data from my import.io extractor. I am then trying to import the data to a MySQL database. I have been following the example given here: http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/511605-extractor-to-sql-database but I am unable to get any data into my database for some reason.  Any help resolving this would be very helpful.  Below is some additional information.

Below is the output when I run the commands found in the tutorial which have been modified a bit for my personal use.

```
./importSQL.py 
CONFIG FOUND, YAY! 
{u'username': u'dmhumph_dmhumph', u'database': u'dmhumph_WATERFOWLGEARFINDER', u'inputUrl': u'https://www.rogerssportinggoods.com/decoys/avery-greenhead-gear-decoys/full-body-goose.html', u'mapping': {u'product_name/_text': u'product_name', u'image/_alt': u'product_name2', u'image': u'image', u'availability': u'availability', u'price': u'price', u'product_name/_title': u'product_name3', u'product_name': u'link'}, u'host': u'localhost', u'table': u'FullBodyGeese', u'ioAPIKey': u'<API-Key-Here>', u'password': u'<Password-Here>', u'sourceUUID': u'<Source-UUID-Here>', u'port': 3306, u'ioUserID': u'<IO-User-ID-Here>'} 
Recieved 1 rows of data 
product_name, product_name2, image, availability, price, product_name3, link 
Mappings: {u'product_name/_text': u'product_name', u'image/_alt': u'product_name2', u'image': u'image', u'availability': u'availability', u'price': u'price', u'product_name/_title': u'product_name3', u'product_name': u'link'}
```

Below is a sample of the data returned when I just go out and get the data from the same extractor and dump it to a file:

```
    stdClass Object
    (
        [offset] => 0
        [results] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [product_name/_text] => Avery GHG Tim Newbold Lesser Canadas Sleeper 4 Pack
                        [image] => https://www.rogerssportinggoods.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/210x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/A/V/AV-72322-550.png
                        [price] => Regular Price: $99.99 Special Price $44.99
                        [availability] => Out of stock
                        [image/_alt] => Avery GHG Tim Newbold Lesser Canadas Sleeper 4 Pack
                        [product_name] => https://www.rogerssportinggoods.com/decoys/avery-greenhead-gear-decoys/full-body-goose/avery-ghg-tim-newbold-lesser-canadas-sleeper-4-pack.html
                        [product_name/_title] => Avery GHG Tim Newbold Lesser Canadas Sleeper 4 Pack
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [product_name/_text] => Avery GHG 72302 Tim Newbold Fully Flocked Lesser Canadas Sleepers
                        [image] => https://www.rogerssportinggoods.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/210x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/A/V/AV-72302-550.png
                        [price] => Regular Price: $129.99 Special Price $69.99
                        [availability] => Out of stock
                        [image/_alt] => Avery GHG 72302 Tim Newbold Fully Flocked Lesser Canadas Sleepers
                        [product_name] => https://www.rogerssportinggoods.com/decoys/avery-greenhead-gear-decoys/full-body-goose/avery-ghg-tim-newbold-fully-flocked-lesser-canadas-sleepers.html
                        [product_name/_title] => Avery GHG 72302 Tim Newbold Fully Flocked Lesser Canadas Sleepers
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [product_name/_text] => Greenhead Gear Pro Grade Series Full Body Canada Goose Decoys
                        [image] => https://www.rogerssportinggoods.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/210x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/A/V/AV-71446-500.png
                        [price] => Regular Price: $139.99 Special Price $89.99
                        [availability] => Out of stock
                        [image/_alt] => Greenhead Gear Pro Grade Series Full Body Canada Goose Decoys
                        [product_name] => https://www.rogerssportinggoods.com/decoys/avery-greenhead-gear-decoys/full-body-goose/greenhead-gear-pro-grade-series-full-body-canada-goose-decoys.html
                        [product_name/_title] => Greenhead Gear Pro Grade Series Full Body Canada Goose Decoys
                    )
)

    [cookies] => Array
        (
            [0] => frontend="q7jjmij9u3jlnh505vl2d1oa45";Path="/";Domain="www.rogerssportinggoods.com";Port="443"
            [1] => CATEGORY_INFO="%5B%5D";Path="/";Domain="www.rogerssportinggoods.com";Port="443"
            [2] => LAST_CATEGORY="70";Path="/";Domain="www.rogerssportinggoods.com";Port="443"
    )
        [connectorVersionGuid] => 44b6228b-c59c-47a0-8cbf-458fabe5d77d
        [connectorGuid] => 4a60b47a-b973-4e51-8e15-47cf81fb1858
        [pageUrl] => https://www.rogerssportinggoods.com/decoys/avery-greenhead-gear-decoys/full-body-goose.html
        [outputProperties] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => product_name
                        [type] => URL
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => image
                        [type] => IMAGE
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => price
                        [type] => STRING
                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => availability
                        [type] => STRING
                    )

            )

    )
```